# Сокращение слова "год"

Tags: стилистика, сокращения

В тексте праздничного обращения пишется "год" без сокращений, а в заголовке и подписи - "г.".
Например:
Торжества 9 мая 2011 г.
Текст обращения.
Москва, 9 мая 2011 г.
Или лучше писать везде "год" не сокращая?

Попутный вопрос. В каком порядке правильнее писать в подписи: сначала город или дату?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"9 мая 2011 года", "9 мая 2011 г." — оба варианта корректны. Что предпочесть — дело вкуса. По-моему, со словам "торжества" стилистически лучше сочетается полное написание:  **Торжества 9 мая 2011 года**.

Подпись под фотографией: "Москва, 9 мая 2011 г." или "9 мая 2011 г., Москва"?
Не думаю, что есть правила на этот счет, но второй вариант мне не нравится.